# Using Git in R-studio: cannot stage modified code files

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio

I am new to using git and currently employ the following combination:

- Git-Gui v.0.20
- R-studio 0.99.489
- R 3.22
- Bitbucket code repository
- Windows 7

Until recently this combination worked fine for pulling and pushing code to the repository. But now I cannot push modified code anymore nor commit it in R-studio. 
In R-studio, modified code is marked by a blue M with a checkbox next to it. I cannot check this box for staging, committing and pushing anymore. It literally does not check and react when I click on it.

When I create a new code sniplet which shows as yellow question mark ? I can check and push it, but modified versions cannot be checked anymore.

I have already deinstalled git and R-studio and re-installed but the problem persists. I also created a new repository but the problem occured in the new repository as well. I am a bit clueless where to start looking for a soluation and a web search did not yield many results except this discussion [here](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/322), which I cannot fully follow because it perhaps does not apply fully to my problem. In any case when I give

```
> Sys.which('git')
```

R returns:

```
git 
 ""
```

I would appreciate advice where to go from here.

Comment: what os? either you don't have git installed or it is not in your `PATH`, what about under `rstudio > global options > git/svn > git executable`, what does that say

Comment: Windows 7. In Rstudio the path is properly specified (`C:/Git-Software/bin/git.exe`). Rstudio also successfully downloads an existing project from bitbucket which shows that some of git's functions are working properly. For example, if I delete the project, I can download the project again (but then all functions are in their state of the time when they were uploaded first because modifications don't work).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found an answer to my question. It is a bug in RStudio, albeit not a very well documented one.

When there is a space in the `.R` file name, it is not possible to push the file through git. Removing the space solves the problem.

See [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202684518-RStudio-Git-cannot-Stage-with-SPACE-in-R-filename) for an official comment on the Rstudio board dating February 2015. I am using the most recent version of Rstudio and it is not yet fixed there.

Comment: Nice. More accurate than my answer (which was more about Git itself). +1

Comment: Nobody (you cannot get your own bounty), unless you manually allocate the bounty to my answer (I won't protest if you do ;) )

Comment: it seems to be the same with dashes (-) in the file or path name name

Comment: On the RStudio support list I linked above somebody reports the same problem for spaces in folder names.

Comment: Does anyone know if this problem has been resolved?

Comment: Answering my own question: this appears to have been fixed in version 1.0a in December 2016.

Answer (score 4):

Try if the issue persists with:

- the [latest git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) unzipped anywhere you want: [`PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit.7z.exe)
- its path added to `%PATH%`:

  ```
  set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit\bin
  ```
- its path declare in R-Studio `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit\bin\git.exe`
- R-Studio itself launched from a `CMD` session where %PATH% already references git.

Comment: Thanks -- I executed the second step from `CMD`. I declared the path in Rstudio using dialoge "global options-->Git". Correct so far? How do I launch Rstudio from `CMD` session?

Comment: I started `CMD`, went to the installation path of RStudio and then started it by `rstudio.exe`. Is this correct?

Comment: @ThomasKlausch I don't know R-Studio enough to know how it is launched from CMD: check the properties of its shortcut. But the idea is to launch it from an environment where git is in `%PATH%` (meaning from the same CMD where you executed the second step).

Comment: Okay doing this and giving `sys.which('git')` now returns the correct %PATH%

Comment: The problem persists though. Sorry.