# Rename R script without deleting Git record

Tags: r, git, version-control, rename, delete-file

I am very new to using Git in RStudio, and have just found out about the problems with spaces in file names when trying to stage a modified document. ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34105129/using-git-in-r-studio-cannot-stage-modified-code-files))

As a result, I need to rename my scripts. When I have tried this, it thinks my scripts have been deleted, and I have had to re-add all of my files, meaning that any previous versions have not copied across. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to preserve history on the file

```
git mv oldfilename newfilename
```

Comment: Does this script rename the files, or does this simply copy the history? I.e. I'll need to add the new files, (keeping the old ones), then running this script then deleting the old ones?

Comment: This will rename the file, and preserve the git history. No need to add new files if you are just looking to rename the files.

Comment: When I tried this it shows as deleted (I am also using git in Rstudio).  If I access the history for the 'new' file, it does not show the history for the 'old' file.